# Python TypeError: xlabel() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

Tags: python

```
import os, pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Change this to match your directory where the file is stored
os.chdir(r'Z:\\My Documents') 
#Read the CSV into Python, setting the first column as the index and    the     first row as the column names
series = pd.read_csv('Energy.csv', header=0,index_col = 0)
series = series.transpose() 
x = series.columns
print(series.head())

name = series.index.values
plt.figure(figsize = (11.69,8.27))

for i,values in enumerate(series.values):
    plt.bar(x,values, label = name[i])
    plt.xlabel(label = "VOC", loc = 'best')
    plt.ylabel(label = "VOC", loc = 'best')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
```

Hello all

I am trying to run the above code and it keeps saying:

```
TypeError: xlabel() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'
```

I have moved the positional argument and it still throwing up errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try adding the legend this way instead https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 3):

`xlabel` (and `ylabel`) expects the first parameter to be the string to use ([see doc here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)), so replace `plt.xlabel(label = "VOC", loc = 'best')` with `plt.xlabel("VOC")`, then do the same for `ylabel`

Comment: I tried that and got this instead `AttributeError: Unknown property loc`

Comment: That's because `loc` is also not defined anymore for `xlabel`. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks.  Working now, I think it was because I was defining loc.